# MATLAB - How to find max difference with long format

Tags: matlab

```
t(1)= 0;
y0= 3;
y(1)= y0;
h=0.1;
for n = 1:11
    k1 = 2*y(n)+(t(n))^2;
    k2 = 2*(y(n)+h/2*k1)+(t(n)+h/2^2);
    k3 = 2*(y(n)+h/2*k2)+(t(n)+h/2)^2;
    k4 = 2*(y(n)+h*k3)+(t(n)+h)^2;
    t(n+1) = t(n)+h;
    y(n+1) = y(n)+h/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);
end

t1(1)= 0;
y1(1)= y0;
h1=0.01;
for n = 1:101
    k1 = 2*y1(n)+(t1(n))^2;
    k2 = 2*(y1(n)+h1/2*k1)+(t1(n)+h1/2^2);
    k3 = 2*(y1(n)+h1/2*k2)+(t1(n)+h1/2)^2;
    k4 = 2*(y1(n)+h1*k3)+(t1(n)+h1)^2;
    t1 (n+1) = t1(n)+h1;
    y1 (n+1) = y1(n)+h1/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);    
end
```

`plot (t,y,t1,y1)` will show very similar curves, In this plot MAX difference may be very small, such as 0.001, 0.0001 or whatever. Actually, I want more clearly the difference, and `plot (t,y,t1,y1)` doesn't work so good. I think `long format` for k1,..,k4 and y is appropriate. Also, I tried

```
z (1) = 0;
for j = 2:11
z = [ y (j) - y ( (j-1)*10*1 ) (11) ];
end
```

Comment: It's nice to give some sort of introduction to a problem before jumping to the code. Please describe the problem more thouroughly

Comment: Changing to long format isn't going to change what `plot` gives you. If you want to better visualize small values then you should scale your outputs by some constant or see if a logarithmic scale would be appropriate.

Comment: would it solve your problem if you tried to visualize the difference between y1 and y next to your plots?

Answer (score 1):

What about plotting the difference explicitly. Interpolate to get `y` at `t1`:

```
y_t1 = interp1(t,y,t1);
plot(t1,y_t1-y1)
```

[image]

On an unrelated note, you are growing a vector inside a loop. No doubt mlint has told you this is bad. Rather initialize your vectors like this:

```
t = zeros(1,11); % i.e. don't do this: t(1)= 0;
```